# Kivy Clock unscheduling and rescheduling issue

Tags: python, kivy

I have a program that unschedule and reschedule clocks quite often. Then I found sometimes clock object stacks without being unscheduled.

Here is an example of what happens.

```
def functionA(self):
    if self.clock_variable is None:
        self.clock_variable = Clock.schedule_interval(self._function, 1)

...

def functionB(self):
    if self.clock_variable is not None:
        self.clock_variable.cancel()
        self.clock_variable = None
```

This sort of tasks, although it looks like it shouldn't, rarely cause a problem that clock object does not get removed and sleeps inside of self.clock_variable.

In Kivy, when assigning a clock variable, I can assign 2 or more clock objects in one variable like below.

```
variable = Clock.schedule_interval(func, 1) # First Clock
variable = Clock.schedule_interval(func, 2) # Second Clock
```

This doesn't cancel the first clock object and both clock objects remain. However, when I try to unschedule them. I can only unschedule the one I scheduled at last.

For example, the codes below would only unschedule the Second Clock. and I have no way to unschedule or remove the First Clock

```
variable.cancel()
variable.cancel() # Even if I cancel() twice, it works only once.
```

This is a huge problem because my system's CPU goes 20% to 90% when this occurs since clock object stacks inside a variable, and I have no way to remove them.

In Conclusion, I am looking for a way to limit a clock object to be assign only one by one to a variable. This problem only occurred when I loaded kivy program on Linux embedded system(with a single core low performance board).

Comment: Every time you use `variable = `, the previous value of `variable` is over-written. You cannot store multiple values in a simple variable. Consider using a `List` instead of a simple variable.

Comment: @JohnAnderson But then the list will grow exponentially. And if I am going to cancel them all and empty the list sometimes, then I don't know if that is any better than canceling a clock every time.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. My only point is that your statement `In Kivy, when assigning a clock variable, I can assign 2 or more clock objects in one variable like below` is incorrect. If you want to store more than one `ClockEvent` you need to use something other than a simple variable, like a `List` that can be used as  stack.

Comment: @JohnAnderson What I meant was that I can assign multiple clocks to a variable but I can only reference the one that is assigned at last. My problem is that I am trying to cancel and rerun the clock, but sometimes another clock is being assigned before cancelation happens (when cpu goes high I think). And when this happens, a clock object that I can't reference to cancel exists somewhere and runs infinitely. I am looking for a way to cancel them or prevent this from happening.

Answer (score 2):

If you only want one ClockEvent to exist at one time, then simply cancel the previous one before creating a new one:

```
def functionA(self):
    if self.clock_variable is None:
        self.clock_variable = Clock.schedule_interval(self._function, 1)
    else:
        self.clock_variable.cancel()
        self.clock_variable = Clock.schedule_interval(self._function, 1)
```